# PHP - HTML form, connecting with select box options

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, submit

For this project, I have an upload page for the user to upload a CSV file where it is inserted into a DB in one single staging table. From there, some things are split and also inserted into separate tables. Each CSV has 2 to 8 rows, and each row has 228 fields, so there are 228 columns in my staging table.

Once uploaded, the user can go to a page (userSelect.php) and use dropdowns to help select a work order to view where it will be displayed in multiple tables.

The upload/insert works great, and the dropdowns are populating with the elements from the database properly but I can't seem to connect the selections to the table page.

For instance, if the user selects the "Work Order Packet" dropdown and chooses 'February Zone B1', I want this to show links with any record from the database that has this work order packet name. Then, once they select the record they want, I want the display.php page to fill all the tables with the 228 elements from that specific record, using the id I assume.

I have the code for these two pages below. The userSelect page does not currently have any code for showing the database records as links either so i'm hoping to figure out how I can show those and then use the one the user selects to fill the tables on the display page.

**userSelect.php**

```
<form method="post" action="display.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" >
</form>
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pw = "root";
$db = "uwsTest";

$connect = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pw, $db);
if ($connect->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo'success!';
}
?>

<label>Select Work Order Packet:</label>
<select name="workOrderPacket">
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT workOrderPacket FROM staging;");
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option >" . $row['workOrderPacket'] . "</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<label>Select Work Order ID:</label>
<select name="WorkOrderNumber">

<?php

$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT workOrderNum FROM staging;");
while($row2 = $sql2->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option>" . $row2['workOrderNum'] . "</option>";
}
?>  
</select>
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
?>
<!--Qa Table-->
<table>
<tr>
<th colspan="2">Qa/Qc CheckList</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service Address Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['serviceAddress'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Service Loc Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['serviceLoc'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Number Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['meterNumber'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Manufacturer Changed</td>
<td><? echo $row['meterManufacturer'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Type Changed</td>
<td><? echo $row['meterType'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Meter Model Changed</td>
<td><? echo $row['meterModel'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Low Register Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['registerCorrect'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>High Register Correct</td>
<td><? echo $row['registerCorrect'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE - unfinished SQL query for display.php:

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM staging WHERE StageID = ;";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect,$query1);
```

Comment: Please move 
<form method="post" action="display.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> above your PHP code at the top

Comment: Sorry not like that. Just move the form opening tag alone to the top & keep the remaining 2 lines at the bottom itself

Comment: Move as explained above& check if it works

Comment: Oh, I see. That actually isn't making a difference either way. The submit button opens the display.php page without any problem. It's the database side that I'm needing help with so that the tables display the option that the user selected from the dropdown. Currently it just fills up with the latest entry in the database tables

Comment: Oh ok. Do you want to change the WorkOrderNumber dropdown based on the selection in WorkOrderPacket dropdown?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So the filter options would correspond, but also, when the display.php page is opened, it fills the tables based off of the users selection

Comment: Hopefully I'm making sense there, sorry. But these dropdowns are filters so whether one or all are used I want to make sure that the tables in display.php are filled by the selected options record

Comment: You need a bit of jQuery then. I am on a mobile, but I try to post a solution after few hours if no one answered until then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your SQL statement to filter the associated results.

`SELECT workOrderNum FROM staging WHERE workOrderPacket = '.$_REQUEST["workOrderPacket"] ';`

Comment: The way my first SQL statement is now, for workOrderPacket, it puts all work order packet numbers in the select box, which is what I want. But in order to filter the workOrderNum results, do you mean I would need to alter the 2nd SQL statement? So that it only shows work order numbers within that packet?

Comment: Yes, if you would like to filter the workOrderNum results you would need to alter the 2nd statement.  `$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT workOrderNum FROM staging WHERE workOrderPacket = '"$workOrderPacket"';");`

Comment: Ah, I understand and I just tried that with success, thank you! Do you have any ideas as far as making the next page after submission (display.php) fill the tables with the values from the record that corresponds to the selection? In other words, if the user selects workOrderNum 779870, it would fill the tables on display.php with the 228 values from the database record that has 779870 as the work order number?

Comment: I just added an update to my code with an unfinished SQL statement on the display page if it helps

Comment: You will need to add the posted data from the drop down to filter your results on the display.php file.  This means your SQL statement will have it include data from the form.  `SELECT workOrderNum FROM staging WHERE workOrderPacket = '.$_REQUEST["workOrderPacket"] ';`

Comment: One last question: IF the user selected items from all 3 select boxes, how would this $_REQUEST option change on display.php? Say they chose a work order packet, work order number, and serial number, would I just use serial number since it's the last choice?

Comment: `SELECT workOrderNum FROM staging WHERE workOrderPacket = '.$_REQUEST["workOrderPacket"] ' AND serialNumber = '$_REQUEST["serialNumber"]' AND workOrderNumber = '$_REQUEST["workOrderNumber]';`  You just need to add more conditions to the SQL statement to filter the results accordingly.  The $_REQUEST[""] function will grab the data from the form that is submitted

Comment: @squid, can you please correct your answer based on your discussion with H.Norman. I think the answer you posted was not correct one & I hope H.Norman accepted your answer based the discussion.